# How can I avoid getting the "log window full" message in the below code in SAS?

Tags: loops, macros, sas

How can I update the below code so that I don't get the 'log window full' message? Most of the lines generated in the log window are due to proc corr. I tried adding the proc printto line at the beginning of the code but log window still gets filled up for some reason. Thanks.

```
PROC PRINTTO PRINT='C:\Users\test\auto.lst' NEW;
RUN;

%MACRO RunProgram(month, year, n);
data sourceh.group2;
set sourceh.group_&month.&year.;
int1=int;
int2 = ceil(int/2);
int3 = ceil(int/3);
int4 = ceil(int/4);
int5 = ceil(int/5);
int6 = ceil(int/15);
int7 = ceil(int/30);

proc sort data=sourceh.group2;
by symbol day month year int&n.;
run;

proc corr data=sourceh.group2; by symbol day; 
var zone ztwo;
ods output pearsoncorr=sourceh.zcorr;
run;

%MEND ;

%macro l;

%do n=1 %to 7;

%RunProgram(Dec, 2014, &n);
%RunProgram(Nov, 2014, &n);
%end;

%mend;

%l;
```

Comment: Try `ODS LISTING CLOSE;`, then `ODS LISTING;` when you want to re-open the listing destination.

Comment: You have moved the listing destination not the log.

Comment: Why is `PROC CORR` filling your log?  Maybe there is an issue that should be addressed?

Comment: Thanks so much, I realized I hadn't erased ods trace on, which was also filling the log file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect your log using proc
Printto.

```
Proc printto log='templog.log' new;
Run;
```

You can reset if afterwards using

```
 Proc printto log=log; run;
```

Alternatively you can set the option nonotes on so that the log doesn't get output unless there's an error. This can make it hard to debug.

```
 Option nonotes;
```

Turn notes option back on:

```
 Option notes;
```

Comment: Thanks. Where should I put those lines  in the program? Should they go inside the macro?

Comment: Which option are you using? If proc printto place it before the macro. If notes option them place inside,the macro, nonotes at the top and reset to notes at the bottom. These are suggestions but they can be placed in several diff location.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I think you should output your log so that you can check to see if something's gone wrong; Reeza's answer addresses this approach. However, you can also just clear the log by using the command

```
dm 'clear log';
```

If you insert this as the first or last line of your RunProgram macro, your log will clear on each iteration of the macro. This will get rid of your problem so long as one iteration of the macro doesn't fill up your log.